# gethostbyname on remote client but getting sometimes 'Resource temporarily unavailable'

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection, client-server

**sometimes**, expecially when client and server are on different machines (one in my ubuntu and the other one in a virtual-machined ubuntu), the client which tries to connect to the server via hostname gets a

> Error getHostEntry: Resource temporarily unavailable.

This is the server.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void checkHostname(int);

void checkHostEntry(struct hostent*);
void checkIpBuffer(char*);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddress;
    int socketDescriptor, clientDescriptor, nread;
    char buffer[1000];
    pthread_t threadId;
    char hostbuffer[256];
    char *IPbuffer;
    struct hostent *hostEntry;
    int hostname;

if((socketDescriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("Errore durante la creazione della socket\n");
    exit(1);
}

socketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
socketAddress.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

if(bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*) &socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress)) != 0) {
    printf("Errore di bind()\n");
    close(socketDescriptor);
    exit(1);
}

hostname = gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer)); 
checkHostname(hostname); 

hostEntry = gethostbyname(hostbuffer); 
checkHostEntry(hostEntry); 

IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) hostEntry->h_addr_list[0])); 

printf("Hostname - %s\n", hostbuffer); 
printf("Host IP - %s:%d\n", IPbuffer, ntohs(socketAddress.sin_port)); 

if(listen(socketDescriptor, 100) < 0) {
    printf("Errore di listen()\n");
    close(socketDescriptor);
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
}

void checkHostname(int hostname) {
    if (hostname == -1) {
        perror("Errore gethostname");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void checkHostEntry(struct hostent *hostentry) {
    if (hostentry == NULL) {
        perror("Errore getHostEntry");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void checkIpBuffer(char *ip) {
    if (ip == NULL) {
        perror("Errore inet_ntoa");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And this is my client.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netdb.h> 


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    int choice, nread, serverIp;
    char *IPbuffer; 
    struct hostent *host_entry; 


    if((clientDescriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Errore nella creaione del socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    host_entry = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
   checkHostEntry(host_entry)

    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));                     

    clientAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPbuffer); // indirizzo IP
    clientAddress.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));  // porta

    if(connect(clientDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddress, sizeof(clientAddress)) < 0) {
        printf("Errore connect()\n");
        close(clientDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
void checkHostEntry(struct hostent *hostentry) {
        if (hostentry == NULL) {
            perror("Errore getHostEntry");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

If I

```
./server.out 8888
```

it displays:

```
IP: 1.2.3.4
Hostname: johnmayer
```

and If i try to connect from another computer (with a ubuntu installed on a virtual box) to this server, using

```
./client johnmayer 8888
```

I **sometimes** get

> Error getHostEntry: Resource temporarily unavailable.

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Attach a debugger and find out exactly where it seg faults. Using a debugger is the best way to find your own bugs.

Comment: For starters, do proper error checking. For example, check the return value of `gethostbyname` before using it. Again, a debugger can tell you almost immediately whether or not that is returning NULL resulting in a NULL pointer dereference.

Comment: @kaylum gethostbyname is checked: `hostEntry = gethostbyname(hostbuffer); 
checkHostEntry(hostEntry);` where `checkHostEntry()` function is specified in the code I have attached.

Comment: That's in the server. Which is irrelevant as it is the client that is crashing right? Check the client code.

Comment: I added that check and it returns **Resource temporarily unavailable**

Comment: POST EDITED with further information.

Comment: That's unlikely to be caused by your code. More likely network or system issues. But unlikely to be able to diagnose the problem within the context of this question as it is probably not a coding issue.

Comment: If I run these programs on two compuiters without virtual machines, it works properly...